# Prefix and postfix operator

Tags: post-increment, pre-increment, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int x=5, y;
    y=x+++x;
    printf("%d", x);
    printf("%d", y);
}
```

What I found is that postfix increment has higher precedence than prefix.
Hence
`y=x+++x;`
`y=(x++)+x;`
`y=10`
`x=6`
But when I execute the program `:y=11,x=6`
Please correct me if I am understanding anything wrong

Comment: Please tag the programming language that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting it down and remembering that there is also the "right-left rule"
This is a simple rule that allows you to interpret any declaration. It runs as follows:

> Start reading the declaration from the innermost parentheses, go right, and then go left.

So, parsing Right-to-Left in the absence of parentheses:

`x=5`, so using the prefix operator `++x` increments the value before `y` is assigned.

Then an assignment is made to `y` equivalent to `5+6` (i.e. `x+(++x)`)

`x` was incremented, so `x=6`

Comment: This assumes you are in a C or C++ language.